# FireFox https SSL profile error in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, https

FireFox HTTPS SSL profile error in Selenium, I tried the code. But still I'm getting the same error.

```
WedDriver driver;
        ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();               
        FirefoxProfile ffProfile=new FirefoxProfile();
        ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
```

[image: webpage error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access your website with IP address and that rising an error in browsers. SSL certificate can only be issued on FQDN (**fully qualified domain name**) and it should be accessed by the same. Try to access your website with FQDN and browser will let you access with HTTPS.